# Invalid token '=' in class struct interface in c# program

Tags: c#

```cs
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
    public class Book
    {
        public string title;
        public string author;
        public int pages;
        Book.pages = 10;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the invalid token error. Please help.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax. If you want to initialize pages to 10  you should do `public int pages=10;` or create a constructor and write `pages =10;` in the constructor.

Comment: It's the last line. You can't execute code just within the class declaration. It would need to be in the constructor or another method. Or if you want a default value just write `public int pages = 10;`

Comment: Oh i see okay thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code, if you want to set default value for pages.

```
public class Book
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; } = 10;
}
```

But if you want to set value after create your class you can use this code:
first time you should create instance of your object and set value.

```
public class Book
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
}
Book book = new Book { pages = 10 };
```

And you can also use `constructor` to set default value.

```
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        this.pages = 10;
    }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; } 
}
```